# Creating 3 column TAB file using name of files in directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have over 100 files in a directory with format `xxx_1_sequence.fastq.gz` and `xxx_2_sequence.fastq.gz`

The goal is to create a TAB file with 3 columns in this format:

```
xxx ---> xxx_1_sequence.fastq.gz ---> xxx_2_sequence.fastq.gz
```

where `--->` is a tab.

I was thinking of creating a for loop or maybe using string manipulation in order to achieve this. My knowledge is rudimentary at this stage, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Typically you get more help if you have tried to solve your problem. The thing you want is called regular expressions and this is a link which might help https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions

Comment: Consider posting (short) sample input files, and include the expected output. It's not clear what you would like to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are in a directory called `files`:

```
paste -d '\t' \
    <(printf "%s\n" files/*_1_sequence.fastq.gz | sort) \
    <(printf "%s\n" files/*_2_sequence.fastq.gz | sort) \
    | sed 's/\(.*\)_1_sequence.fastq.gz/\1\t\1_1_sequence.fastq.gz/' \
    > out.tsv
```

Explanation:

`printf "%s\n"` will print every argument in a new line. So:

```
printf "%s\n" files/*_1_sequence.fastq.gz | sort
```

prints a sorted list of the first type of files (the second column in your output). And of course it's symmetrical with `*_2_sequence.fastq.gz` (the third column).

(We probably don't need the `sort` part, but it helps clarify the intention.)

The syntax `<(some shell command)` runs `some shell command`, puts its output into a temporary input file, and passes that file as an argument. You can see the temporary file like so:

```
$ echo <(echo a) <(echo b)
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
```

So we are passing 2 (temporary) files to `paste`. If each output file has N lines, then `paste` outputs N lines, where line number K is a concatenation of line K of each of the files, in order.

For example, if line 4 of the first file is `hello` and line 4 if the second file is `world`, `paste` will have `hello\tworld` as line 4 of the output. But instead of trusting the default, we're setting the delimiter to TAB explicitly with `-d '\t'`.

That gives us the last 2 columns of our tab-separated-values file, but the first column is the `*` part of `*_1_sequence.fastq.gz`, which is where `sed` comes in.

We tell `sed` to replace `\(.*\)_1_sequence.fastq.gz` with `\1\t\1_1_sequence.fastq.gz`. `.*` will match anything, and `\(some-pattern\)` tells sed to remember the text that matched the pattern.

The first parentheses in `sed`'s regex are can be read back into the replacement pattern as `\1`, which is why we have `\1_1_sequence.fastq.gz` in the replacement pattern.

But now we can also use `\1` to create the first column of our tsv, which is why we have `\1\t`.

Comment: Hi- thankyou so much for your help. I was thrown into a bioinformatics position a week ago with no coding experience and I have been struggling. I ended up with this:

printf "%s\n" *_1_sequence.fastq.gz | sort | sed 's/\(.*\)_1_sequence.fastq.gz/\1\t\1_1_sequence.fastq.gz\t\1_2_sequence.fastq.gz/ ' > NULLARBORformat.tab

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
shopt -s extglob                # enable extended pattern matching
suffix="sequence.fastq.gz"
for f in !(*"$suffix"); do      # files which does not match the pattern
    if [[ -f ${f}_1_$suffix && -f ${f}_2_$suffix ]]; then
                                # check the existence of the files just in case
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$f" "${f}_1_$suffix" "${f}_2_$suffix"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for the help guys- I was thrown into a coding position a week ago with no prior experience and have been struggling.

I ended up with this `printf "%s\n" *_1_sequence.fastq.gz | sort | sed 's/\(.*\)_1_sequence.fastq.gz/\1\t\1_1_sequence.fastq.gz\t\1_2_sequence.fastq.gz/ ' > NULLARBORformat.tab`

and it does the job perfectly!